# KVC - key value coding with dot seperation - Exception not KVC compliant

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, key-value-coding, kvc

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
@property NSArray *arr;
@end
@inplementation MyClass
- (instancetype) init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        self.arr = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass *temp = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [temp valueForKey:@"arr.count"];    //count is ivar of NSArray
    return 0;
}
```

then console says

> NSExceptions: [MyClass valueForUnfinedKey:] this class is not key
>   value-complaint for the key arr.count

Everytime I use dot seperations, this `exceptions` come out.

I tried to search web and read menu, I still don't know why, could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `valueForKey:` takes a single key (property or local variable) name, it does not take a key path such as your `arr.count`.

The method `valueForKeyPath:` does take a key path, it effectively is a sequence of `valueForKey:` calls. See *Getting Attribute Values Using Keys* in [About Key-Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-BAJEAIEE).

**However** you example will still not work due to the way `valueForKey:` is defined for [`NSArray`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1412219-valueforkey?language=objc):

> Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.

So in your case if you try `valueForKeyPath:@"arr.count"`, the `arr` part of the path will return your array and then `NSArray`'s `valueForKey:` will attempt to get the `count` key *for each element of the array* and **not** for the array itself. Not what you want...

Which brings us to [Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) which provide key Paths which do operate on the collection, array in your case, and not its elements. The collection operator you need is `@count` giving you the key path `arr.@count`, so you need to call:

```
[temp valueForKeyPath:@"arr.@count"]
```

Unless this is an exercise in learning about KVC this can be shortened to:

```
temp.arr.count
```

which doesn’t have the issue of trying to apply `count` to the array’s elements, and returns an `NSUInteger` value rather than an `NSNumber` instance.

HTH

Comment: Thanks you so mush, at first I even don't know the different between valueForKey: & valueForKeyPath: and think they are same, I tried to use valueForKeyPath: but failed due to I forgot it is collection object. That do helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `arr.count` is not key value-complaint of MyClass. When program runs, it cann't find any property of MyClass name `arr.count`.

> valueForKeyPath: - Returns the value for the specified key path relative to the receiver. Any object in the key path sequence that is not key-value coding compliant for a particular key—that is, for which the default implementation of valueForKey: cannot find an accessor method—receives a valueForUndefinedKey: message.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now.